# PHP array check if value in specific key exists

Tags: php, arrays

I am using `PHP 5.5.12`.

I have the following multidimensional array:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type":"elephant", 
        "title":"Title of elephant"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 2,
        "type":"tiger", 
        "title":"Title of tiger"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "type":"lion", 
        "title":"Title of lion",
        "children":[{
            "id": 4,
            "type":"cow", 
            "title":"Title of cow"
        },
        {
            "type":"elephant", 
            "title":"Title of elephant"
        },
        {
            "type":"buffalo", 
            "title":"Title of buffalo"
        }]
    }
]
```

I am iterating this array using `foreach` loop.

The array key `type` must be in `elephant`, `tiger` and `lion`. If not, then the result should return `false`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Any source code you wrote so far that we can use as a model?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: So, you want to verify that whether every single key (in every nested level) that named `type` have a valid value (of those you specified)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using PHP5.5.12, you can make use of [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column).

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
//Walk through each element, only paying attention to type
array_walk( array_column($arr, 'type'), function($element, $k) use(&$arr) {
    $arr[$k]['valid_type'] = in_array($element, array('lion', 'tiger', 'elephant'));
});
```

From here, each element in the array (`$arr`) will have a new key `valid_type` with a boolean value - `1` if the type is valid, `0` if it isn't.

https://eval.in/350322

Answer (score 1):

So you want to check if your `$myArray` contains a value or not:

```
// first get all types as an array
$type = array_column($myArray, "type");

// specify allowed types values
$allowed_types = ["lion", "elephant", "tiger"];

$count = count($type);
$illegal = false;

// for loop is better
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    // if current type value is not an element of allowed types
    // array, then both set the $illegal flag as true and break the 
    // loop
    if(!in_array($type[$i], $allowed_types)
        $illegal = true;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this something that you are looking for?

```
foreach($your_array as $item) {
    if (!array_key_exists('type', $item)) {
    return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: *The array key type must be in elephant, tiger and lion. If not, then the result should return false.* - That doesn't check the value of the `type`.

Answer (score -1):

```
function keyExists($arr, $key) {
    $flag = true;

    foreach($arr as $v) {
        if(!isset($v[$key])) {
            $flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $flag;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: *The array key type must be in elephant, tiger and lion. If not, then the result should return false.* - Your code doesn't check the value.

Comment: Im sorry i did not understand the question correctly then. You could just add the test condition in the if condition and it will work as expected.